# How to store listener reference when using Class methods as callbacks?

Tags: javascript

I'm using ES6 Class definition to create small components that, between other things, attach listeners to elements. Since I'm binding a class method as the listeners callback, I'm using `.bind()` to retain the context during event execution.

I wrote a very contrived class just for the sake of clarification:

```
class Test {
    constructor(el) {
        this.x = 10;
        this.elem = el;

        this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.listenerFn.bind(this));
    }

    listenerFn(ev) {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
```

I incur into an issue if I want to, at a later time, destroy this component and detach the listener from the element without destroying the element itself. Since using `.bind()` creates a new function and so simply referencing `this.listenerFn` is not enough.

What I've come up with is to create a map of listeners and use them when attaching/detaching.

Like this:

```
class Test {
    constructor(el) {
        this.x = 10;
        this.elem = el;

        this.listenerPool = {
            'click': this.listenerFn.bind(this),
        }
        this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.listenerPool.click);

        this.elem.test = {
            destroy: this.destroy.bind(this),
        }
    }

    listenerFn(ev) {
        console.log(this.x);
    }

    destroy() {
        this.elem.removeEventListener('click', this.listenerPool.click);
        delete this.elem.test;
    }
}


//...

new Test(document.querySelector('#some_id'));

document.querySelector('#some_id').test.destroy();
```

Although it works, it does not take advantage of the prototype methods and instead make a new copy for each instance of the class, so I wanna know: **Is this correct**?

I would also appreciate if people could share different solutions for the same problem.

Comment: "*it makes a new copy for each instance of the class*" - that's what `bind` always does. In both of your solutions.

Comment: No reason to use an extra "listenerPool" object. Just store the bound function directly on your instance.

Comment: Why did you put that `test` property on the element?

Comment: @Bergi as far as I can tell, it's to have access to the `destroy()` method given a reference to the respective document element.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an entire `listenerPool` to do this, but what's usually done is explicitly binding the member method to the instance in the `constructor`:

```
class Test {
    constructor(el) {
        this.x = 10;
        this.elem = el;

        this.listenerFn = this.listenerFn.bind(this);
        this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.listenerFn);

        // ...
    }

    listenerFn(ev) {
        console.log(this.x);
    }

    destroy() {
        this.elem.removeEventListener('click', this.listenerFn);
    }
}
```

You also want to avoid attaching random user objects to native objects like `elem.test = { destroy: ... }`, as that's pretty analogous to creating global variables, so try to find another way to invoke the class's `destroy()` method from the calling script without attaching it directly to the element.

I would give more specific advice as to how, but you haven't provided the calling code.

Comment: I totally agree with you that in this example the `listenerPool` object is overkill, but in cases where you would have multiple events/listeners, wouldn't the object make more sense?

Comment: Also, I've updated my question and provided some extra calling code, does that suffice for you to give me more specific advices?

Comment: @Rob I'll turn the question back on you by asking what benefit the object serves? I see no added benefit to having an internal event namespace on a class that is supposed to delegate specific behavior for an element. If you have _that_ many events you need to deal with, perhaps you should be more concerned with the granularity of your modularization. Perhaps you need multiple classes, each one dealing with a specific behavior, rather than a single class dealing with every behavior.